# File Tail Inbound Channel Adapter stderr and stdout

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to a tail file using spring integration and it is working as the code below but i have two questions

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel input() {
        return new QueueChannel(50);
    }

   @Bean
   public FileTailInboundChannelAdapterFactoryBean tailInboundChannelAdapterParser() {
       FileTailInboundChannelAdapterFactoryBean x = new FileTailInboundChannelAdapterFactoryBean();
       x.setAutoStartup(true);
       x.setOutputChannel(input());
       x.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
       x.setNativeOptions("-F -n +0");
       x.setFile(new File("/home/shahbour/Desktop/file.txt"));
       return x;
   }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
    public LoggingHandler loggingHandler() {
        return new LoggingHandler("info");
    }


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;

    }
}
```

Per below log i have 4 threads used for tailing the file. Do i need all of them or i can disable some. Why do i have a thread for **Monitoring process java.lang.UNIXProcess@b37e761 , Reading stderr ,Reading stdout** .

I am asking this because i am going to run the program on voip switch and i want to use the minimal resources possible.

```
2016-12-10 13:22:55.666  INFO 14862 --- [ taskExecutor-1] t.OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer : Starting tail process
2016-12-10 13:22:55.665  INFO 14862 --- [           main] t.OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer : started tailInboundChannelAdapterParser
2016-12-10 13:22:55.682  INFO 14862 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer           : started rootConfiguration.loggingHandler.serviceActivator
2016-12-10 13:22:55.682  INFO 14862 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-12-10 13:22:55.701  INFO 14862 --- [           main] c.t.SonusbrokerApplication               : Started SonusbrokerApplication in 3.84 seconds (JVM running for 4.687)
2016-12-10 13:22:55.703 DEBUG 14862 --- [ taskExecutor-2] t.OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer : Monitoring process java.lang.UNIXProcess@b37e761
2016-12-10 13:22:55.711 DEBUG 14862 --- [ taskExecutor-3] t.OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer : Reading stderr
2016-12-10 13:22:55.711 DEBUG 14862 --- [ taskExecutor-4] t.OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer : Reading stdout
```

My Second question is , is it possible to start reading the file from the begging and continue to tail , i was thinking in using native options for this -n 1000

> note: the real code will be to monitor folder for new files as they are created and then start the tail process

Comment: after reading the code of **OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer** i saw that stderror process is needed to check file moved or other error and send it as event , i don't see any way way to disable that , also for reading from start of the file -n +0 is already doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process monitor is needed to `waitFor()` the process - it doesn't use any resources except a bit of memory.

The `stdout` reader is needed to actually handle the data that is produced by the `tail` command.

The starting thread (in your case `taskExecutor-1` exits after it has done its work of starting the other threads).

There is not currently an option to disable the `stderr` reader, but it would be easy for us to add one so there are only 2 threads at runtime.

Feel free to open a [JIRA 'improvement' Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and, of course, [contributions are welcome](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer , i will try to contribute in having an option to disable stderr thread .